# SQL Query for datewise data

Tags: mysql

I've a situation where I need to find the sum of the columns which are defined for a particular date. Plese refer below table:

[image]

In this, I need to find the sum of the numbers date wise i.e. 15 March to 15 June (In the above table months are denoted by number e.g. 5 for May and so on.)

I did that for particular month for each task by below query:

```
select (d1+d2+d3+d4+d5+d6+d7+d8+d9+d10+d11+d12+d13+d14+d15+d16+d17+d18+d19+d20+d21+d22+d23+d24+d25+d26+d27+d28+d29+d30+d31) as HourSum from table1 where Month='<Given Month>';
```

I don't want query but idea to sum only half or less of the column values addition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for d1 and d2

```
select sum(d1)+sum(d2) HourSum from table1 group by month,year
```

refer about "group by"
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

**Updated answer:**

I think your table structure is very strange you should have only one column name date rather then 
having 31 columns(d1-d31).

Anyway, now considering same table structure and data if you want to query data from 15 march 2014 to  15 june 2014 then  you need to write query like below:
-- total sum of d1 to d31

```
select sum(d1) +sum(d2) +sum(d3) +sum(d4) +sum(d5) +sum(d6) +sum(d7) +sum(d8)+sum(d9) +sum(d10) +sum(d11) +sum(d12) +sum(d13) +sum(d14) +sum(d15)+sum(d16) +sum(d17) +sum(d18) +sum(d19) +sum(d20)+sum(d21) +sum(d22) +sum(d23) +sum(d24) +sum(d25) +sum(d26) +sum(d27) +sum(d28) +sum(d29)+sum(d30) +sum(d31) as TotalHours   

from 
(
-- sum 15 march 2014 to 31 march 2014

select 0 as d1,0 as d2,0 as d3, 0 as d5, 0 as d6,0 as d7, 0 as d8,0 as d9,0 as d10,0 as 11,0 as 12,0 as d13,0 as d14,sum(d15) as d15,sum(d16) as d16,sum(d17) as d17,sum(d18) as d18,sum(d19) as d19,sum(d20) as d20,sum(d21) as d21,sum(d22) as d22,sum(d23) as d23,sum(d24) as d24,sum(d25) as d25,sum(d26) as d26,sum(d27) as d27,sum(d28) as d28,sum(d29) as d29,sum(d30) as d30,sum(d31) as d31  from table1 where month = 3 and year=2014  group by Month
)t1

 UNION ALL
(
-- sum 1 april 2014 to 31 may 2014

select sum(d1) as d1,sum(d2) as d2,sum(d3) as d3,sum(d4) as d4,sum(d5) as d5,sum(d6) as d6,sum(d7) as d7,sum(d8) as d8,sum(d9) as d9,sum(d10) as d10,sum(d11) as d11,sum(d12) as d12,sum(d13) as d13,sum(d14) as d14,sum(d15),sum(d15) as d15,sum(d16) as d16,sum(d17) as d17,sum(d18) as d18,sum(d19) as d19,sum(d20) as d20,sum(d21) as d21,sum(d22) as d22,sum(d23) as d23,sum(d24) as d24,sum(d25) as d25,sum(d26) as d26,sum(d27) as d27,sum(d28) as d28,sum(d29) as d29,sum(d30) as d30,sum(d31) as d31  from table1 where month in (4,5) and year=2014    group by Month
)t2
UNION ALL
(
-- sum 1 june 2014 to 15 june 2014

select sum(d1) as d1,sum(d2) as d2,sum(d3) as d3,sum(d4) as d4,sum(d5) as d5,sum(d6) as d6,sum(d7) as d7,sum(d8) as d8,sum(d9) as d9,sum(d10) as d10,sum(d11) as d11,sum(d12) as d12,sum(d13) as d13,sum(d14) as d14,sum(d15),sum(d15) as d15, 0 as d16,0 as d17, 0 as d18,0 as d19, 0 as d20, 0 as d21, 0 as d22,0 as d23,0 as d24,0 aS d25,0 AS d26,0 as d27,0 as d28,0 as d29,0 as 30,0 as 31 from table1 where month = 6 and year=2014 group by Month
)t3
```

Again, change your table structure if possible..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can I create query with dynamic dates. For example if it is from 15 May to 14 June then sum(d15)+sum(d16)+..sum(31) for May but what about for 1 to 14th June. This is the most confusing scenario.

Comment: @Moksh: 1th to 14th data sum will be displayed in Jun month..if you want sum of any particular month then you can add a condition of month in where clause.

Comment: @ZafarMalik: Yes. but How would I put all this in one query? If I put a where clause as Month='5' then 1 to 14 of May also be calculated. Am I right?

Comment: Your query is not clear..I think you are saying that 1st to 14th jun..if you use Month=5 then jun data will not be included if you want to say something else then plz elaborate...

Comment: @Moksh I have updated the query please try it and let me know if it works or not

Comment: @RonakShah: Thanks. It is working as I wanted. I prepared this query dynamically for different dates.